# Prevent widget from being rebuilt

Tags: flutter

A bit of a Flutter newbie, I hope you can help with this question.

I have two widgets on the main screen of my app. the top widget is a Facebook banner ad widget, the bottom part of the screen is then taken up with a list that is populated from an web API call.

When I use the toolbar to refresh the data from the API, I am using SetState to rebuild the list etc.

However, the top widget, with the Facebook ad is also being rebuilt each time, which is not what I want.

I have seen lots of talk about Bloc Patterns etc. If sounds like a bit of overkill for what I want to do, is there an easier way to just update the list without updating the banner ad widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should add a [key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html) property to your widget, it allows you to keep a specific widget from rebuilding when changing state.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions:

1. move the list to a separate StatefulWidget. If setState() is now called in this widget, only the included widget will be rebuilt.
2. something in the direction:

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Widget _facebookBanner;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _facebookBanner = ...;
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      _facebookBanner,
      ListView(...),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Facebook banner as `const`, it won't be rebuilt when declared like that

This is an example of how to use `const` keyword

```
child: const Text('This is just an example of a const widget');
```

Const constructors are a great optimization for stuff that you know that won't change.

Comment: What if I have dynamic content in the `Widget`? it is throwing error: Value is not const.